# Какую технику использовать при анимации графики (изображений) при прокрутке?

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, canvas, svg

Есть страница. При прокрутке происходит смена одного блока другим. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы некоторые картинки анимировались. Есть много таких сайтов, вы наверняка их видели, но я, к сожалению, сейчас пример предоставить не могу.

У меня есть 2 варианта:

1. Анимировать SVG после прокрутки.
   Проблема: я не знаю, какими средствами это делать. При помощи JS? (собственно, **это и есть вопрос**)
2. После прокрутки вставлять скриптом GIF-изображение.
   Проблема: не считаю это правильным решением.

Итак, я думаю, что стоит использовать SVG в таком случае. Но как заставить SVG анимироваться? Нужно сразу прорисовывать в редакторе картинку до анимации и после? Или прорисовывать изменения динамически через JS?

P.S. Пока писал это подумал, что еще можно использовать canvas. Как вы считаете, что лучше в такой ситуации?

https://atom.io/
Это пример сайта, но здесь анимация происходит постоянно (пониже там), а мне нужно, чтобы она запускалось по событию и происходила не циклически, а до какого-то определенного состояния.

Comment: зайди на codepan там куча примеров

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich Мне не столько примеры нужны, сколько осмысление того, чем в такой ситуации лучше пользоваться.

Comment: Читайте блоги, этот сайт не для таких вопросов, если конечно правила сайта читали. Откройте хабр хотя бы там полно статей на эту тему.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/user/uwebdesign Рекомендую этот бложик, там как раз по теме будет, да и не скучно.